# Venv in pycharm is always orange

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm VENV folder won't turn back from orange colour.

Hello,
I recently started using git in PyCharm. The venv folder in the project I was working in turned orange, which I believe is supposed to happen. However, it did not change back from orange when I added it to the gitignore file.
On top of this, every new project I open in PyCharm has an orange venv folder as soon as I open it, and I am not sure how to change it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Call me a cynic, but is it really worth wasting your valuable time worrying about this?

Comment: Well I am not concerned about the colour, I am wondering if there is an underlying issue with it

Comment: This is purely a PyCharm item: see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010251079-What-do-the-background-colors-in-Project-view-mean-